# Design considerations for large ratio step-down transformation

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, high-current

What are the design considerations for a system in which a high voltage and current DC soliton pulse (approximately 50kJ at 45kV over 100ms) from a capacitor bank or PFN must be stepped down to a low voltage DC pulse (say 5v)?

The source is an ex-military HV capacitor bank. I would like to step it down as far as possible for safety reasons, and since I am trying to use Joule heating to sinter alloys of mostly rare earths (powder metallurgy).

Would the best solution be to use a monolithic transformer for this purpose, or are there better ways to do it? I imagine that very hefty, low-resistance conductors would need to be used on both ends, with an improbable number of turns on the primary.

In practical terms, I know that this sort of transformation is done in systems used for capacitor discharge sintering, pulse welding, or possibly in high-energy physics experimentation. How is this typically accomplished in such scenarios?

Comment: You need to ask a technical question based on EE and not ask if there are geeks around with hints. That is not valid for this site.

Comment: Start by defining current, joules and DCR , ESR of C required.

Comment: I would think that insulation/separation would be #1 so current could not bridge from primary to secondary.

Comment: 100,000 A at 5V ! [!!!] [!!!!!!!]. | This SOUNDS like eg Lightning energy capture. Is it? If not, what is the application. More detail usually helps heaps. | Does the output have to be a simiarly shaped Soliton? What are you trying to achieve - capture the energy with output waveform relatively unimportant? - or is waveform important? Why 5V. Why not 400V or 11 kV or ... . does efficiency matter much. eg is 5% or 10% acceptable or ...? | If it's lightning then use of an intermediate mode may be useful - steam or thermal single phase or ... .

Comment: No, I am not using lightning - it is an ex-military HV capacitor bank. I would like to step it down as far as possible for safety reasons, and since I am trying to sinter alloys of mostly rare earths (powder metallurgy).